# Django redirect and modify GET parameters

Tags: django

I am implementing magic tokens and would like clean URLs. As a consequence, I would like to remove the token from the URL upon a successful user authentication.  This is my attempt:

```
def authenticate_via_token(get_response):
    def middleware(request):
      if request.session.get('authenticated', None):
        pass
      else:
        token = request.GET.get('token', None)
        if token:
          mt = MagicToken.fetch_by_token(token)
          if mt:
            request.session['authenticated'] = mt.email
            if not request.GET._mutable:
              request.GET._mutable = True
              request.GET['token'] = None
              request.GET._mutable = False
          else:
            print("invalid token")

      response = get_response(request)
      return response

    return middleware
```

IE, I would like to send `/products/product-detail/3?token=piyMlVMrmYblRwHcgwPEee` --> `/products/product-detail/3`

It's possible that there may be additional GET parameters and I would like to keep them. Any input would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi Phil, can you explain what your solution does not accomplish or where it has issues? Or are you looking for a different way of handling things?

Comment: Can you build an expression of GET parameters, like so `params = '?'+''.join(map(lambda param: f'{param}={request.GET.get(param)}', request.GET))` , and then do something like `HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('productDetailPageName') + params, kwargs={'pk':3})`? I'm not sure if i understood the question tbh

Comment: @schillingt The problem I'm running into is that the token parameter still appears in the URL. I think Ricardo's approach might be what I need to try.

Comment: Are you trying to redirect the user or remove the token from `GET` before the view operates on the request?

Comment: @schillingt Sorry for the lack of clarity. I posted a solution below that appears to be passing the tests I had set up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I ended up going for:

```
from django.urls import resolve, reverse
import urllib

def drop_get_param(request, param):
  'helpful for redirecting while dropping a specific parameter'
  resolution = resolve(request.path_info) #simulate resolving the request

  new_params = request.GET.copy() # copy the parameters
  del new_params[param] # drop the specified parameter
  
  reversed = reverse(resolution.url_name, kwargs=resolution.kwargs) # create a base url

  if new_params: #append the remaining parameters
    reversed += '?' + urllib.parse.urlencode(new_params)

  return reversed
```